# Saving files to a VPN in Visual Studio 2010 very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, save, vpn

I'm connecting to a VPN so I can work at home, but when I open small ASPX files and make minor changes and save them, it's incredibly slow.

Also even doing simple things like clicking a different line in the file to move the cursor is lagged noticeably.

Is this a known issue, or is this as I 99% suspect just down to network connection.  I wasn't expecting it to be this slow.

Comment: I think it is just the way VS 'talks' to the files while you are editing, MS Office sometimes does the same thing.  Best bet would be to copy the .ASPX local, make your changes and then reupload or look into using RemoteDesktop to your workstation.

Comment: Hi Tommy, thank you for the reply, I suspect that as well, is there any way to turn off making VS 'talk' to the server, RD isn't really an option as it would add more sloth to an already slow process :(

Answer (score 2):

Working with files over a VPN will be slow, as Visual Studio will be tracking changes in that file while it is open.

1. Try disabling 'Track Changes' in Visual Studio, under Text Editor section in options.
2. Failing that, you should copy the files to your local machine and work from there, when finished copy back. You can use the folder to sort by last modified to make it easier to find the edited files when you copy back.
3. Ideally, when working with remote codebases, you should use a repository rather than flat file storage. Something like GIT or SVN, and then 'push' your code changes back.

[image: Track Changes Option]

In any case, working over VPN always is always slow. Check VPN settings (compression, multilink), perhaps map the remote folder to a network drive, turn of 'use default gateway' on the VPN connection itself; these are methods I use to speed up VPN performance in general.